# Finding daily patterns in timestamps data with python

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence

So i want to analyze database data of smart house. This is how data i have look like:

```
ID   NAME   STATUS TIME   
1    light  1      2016-06-25 08:00:00
2    light  1      2016-06-25 08:01:05
3    light  1      2016-06-25 08:00:21
4    light  1      2016-06-25 08:00:30
...
```

Basically to calculate all i need is divide (number of light turns on at certain hour) by number of different dates at certain hour.

Comment: To be able to find patterns, such as turning on the light at 8 a.m it would just entail looking at every day, checking to see if an event occurs at 8 a.m, then checking to see if the event is "light". Then to be able to determine if they're going to turn it on at 8 a.m tomorrow look at your data and make a prediction. Say, if the user turns the light on at 8 80% of the days, it's likely that they'll turn it on at 8 tomorrow.

Comment: then basically to calculate all i need is divide (number of light turns on at certain hour) divided by (number of different dates at certain hour

Comment: Yes that's one way you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

This script takes lowest and maximum time from database and calculate time between these times.

```
# db.txt
1    light  1      2016-06-25 08:00:00
1    light  1      2016-06-25 08:01:05
1    light  1      2016-06-25 08:00:21
1    light  1      2016-06-25 08:00:30

# python script
import datetime


def data():
    with open('db.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():  
            row = line.split()
            if row[2] == '1':
                yield row[4]


data = sorted(data())
early = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[0], '%H:%M:%S')
lately = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[1], '%H:%M:%S')
sth_between = (lately - early)/2
print (early + sth_between).time()
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: @Harrison Edited.

Comment: this is great if i have only time around 08:00:00 in my database, but soon as i have different time (eg. 16:00:00) calculation is wrong

Comment: Well I didn't see any data from other times. Ok, so I need to know more about conditions or more detailed explanation in your question with all use cases.